# Sharepoint List Calculated Columns and Power Apps Patch

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have created a Power Apps form that currently patches the inputs to all non-calculated columns in Sharepoint list. This is happening through a Submit button.

If I am submitting these data, how do I ensure that all the calculated columns are also updated at the same time in the Sharepoint list? There are about 4-5 columns that calculate based on the values of other columns. And right now they are all coming as 0.0.

Comment: Can you add formula of one of the calculated columns you used as an example to your question? Also, add screenshot of list view data if possible. Is calculated column value updated properly if you create new items directly from SharePoint list?